# Unable to visualize Anova p values, Warning : Reached elapsed time limit

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have written the code for computing Anova between 2 different groups of patient population for the  following [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozguosb8hvk1pjy/HC_BLVP_WM.xlsx?dl=0)

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr)
df.m <- melt(HC_BLVP_WM,id.var= "Subjects")
p <- ggboxplot(df.m , x= "Subjects" , y= "value",
               color = "Subjects", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter",facet.by = "variable",
               scales="free",short.panel.labs = TRUE)+
  xlab("Subjects") + ylab("Volume mm³")+labs(colour = "Subjects") 
p + stat_compare_means(label="p.signif",method = "anova",paired = FALSE)
```

When I run the code and try to plot using `ggboxplot`, I am experiencing following warning message

```
" Warning message:
In stringUnit(units) : reached elapsed time limit "
```

I am unable to see any Anova p values or statistical significance mark (*) in the image as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1itZN.png) , I am using Rstudio 1.0.153 on Ubuntu 16.04 . Could some one please suggest me the where the problem lies, whether it's in my code or is a bug in R or one of the packages?  I have never previously incurred this problem; I was able to plot successfully with p values above each boxplot.

Results of sessionInfo () are

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

    locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.2 ggpubr_0.1.5   magrittr_1.5   ggplot2_2.2.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     dplyr_0.7.4      assertthat_0.2.0 grid_3.4.2      
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       R6_2.2.2         gtable_0.2.0     scales_0.5.0    
 [9] stringi_1.1.5    rlang_0.1.2      lazyeval_0.2.0   bindrcpp_0.2    
[13] tools_3.4.2      stringr_1.2.0    glue_1.1.1       munsell_0.4.3   
[17] compiler_3.4.2   pkgconfig_2.0.1  colorspace_1.3-2 bindr_0.1       
[21] tibble_1.3.4
```

Comment: can't reproduce (ggpubr 0.1.5, R-devel). Can we see the results of `sessionInfo()` please? RStudio and OS are 99.999% likely to be irrelevant.

Comment: @BenBolker, I have edited the question, with the results of sessionInfo(),please kindly let me know if there is any problem

Comment: we need the results of `sessionInfo()` *after* you load the packages with `require()` please ...

Comment: @BenBolker , I have edited the question, could you please let me know what is wrong with my sessionInfo() results